# Angry IP Scanner - no response to test

Tags: port-scanning

When performing a telnet command to a remote FTP port from the Windows command line, it connects as expected.

I have about 20 external hosts to connect to. I've imported the list for the [Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryziber.com) to test, but it fails to get the response from the remote host(s). I've set the preferences in the application so it only tried to connect on the remote machine's port 21.

I've narrowed the list to 1 host and it does not show that port 21 is open. I assume the remote machine's firewall is blocking this connect attempt.

**Question**: Do you know of any other very lightweight apps which can help test multiple hosts?

Answer (score 5):

**[nmap](http://nmap.org/)** is often used for port scanning. It has [many scan methods and supports multiple targets](http://nmap.org/book/man.html).